# three.js trackballcontrol from local disk

Tags: three.js, webgl

The trackballcontrols demo at 
http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html
works great.  But when I download it and the associated files and try to run
it from local disk, it's blank.  I checked and don't find any loaded textures.
How can I get this running from local disk?

Or is there a better example of trackball controls?

I'm running Firefox 20.0 on Linux Mint 14.1 cinnamon.

Thanks!

Comment: What are the associated errors from the console?

Answer (score 1):

If it's all black then it;s probably due to loading textures locally.
This should help:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally

Comment: Thanks, I've read that page.  My test shows all white.  I put in console.log() messages and it appears to be running the init, animate, and render fuctions.  But the screen is all white except the fps icon at the upper left.  When I click the FPS icon it toggles between FPS and MS, but no number is shown there.  The rest of the window is white.

Comment: Then it probably renderer isn't setup okay. Since stats show blank it means that something is not attached well. Could you edit your question and add jsfiddle or put a live link? Thanks.